# How to unpack a DataFrame into separate Series in a function call?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that expects several pandas Series as arguments:

```
def func(s1, s2, s3): 
    print(s1, s2, s3)
```

And a DataFrame df with columns 'A' through 'Z'.

I would like to call the function like this:

```
func(*df[['A', 'D', 'R']])
```

But it appears that unpacking a DataFrame produces just the column names, not the data.  I know that Using the double star I can get the three desired series in a dictionary, but then the names have to match, so that doesn't work here.

Is there a concise syntax for what I want to do?

Bonus question: does the python community call the * and ** splat and double-splat?  This is a very difficult topic to search for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[`df.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get.html)** under `map` , we can unpack the subset to individual series:

```
cols = ['A','D','R']
func(*map(df.get,cols))
```

---

Sample Run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2],"B":[3,4],"C":[4,5]})

def func(s1, s2, s3): 
    print(s1, s2, s3)

cols = ['A','B','C']
func(*map(df.get,cols))

0    1
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64 0    3
1    4
Name: B, dtype: int64 0    4
1    5
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think about the most concise you can get here is

```
func(*[df[c] for c in "ADR"])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the index, you can do:

```
func(*df[['A', 'D', 'R']].T.values)
```

`T` is taking tranpose because otherwise it will be sent row-by-row not column-by-column.